# Authentication installing Chocolatey packages hosted in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, chocolatey, credential-providers

At work, we create nuget packages that we store in VSTS. All developers have added our repository to the global nuget.config (in folder %appdata%\Nuget), created personal access token (PAT), and installed CredentialProvider.VSS.exe.  Therefore restoring nuget packages using the command line, e.g. `nuget.exe restore`, is done without having to supply any passwords or user names.

When using the same recipe for Chocolatey packages, things don't work that well. The [blog at roadtoalm.com](https://roadtoalm.com/2017/05/02/using-vsts-package-management-as-a-private-chocolatey-gallery/) describes how you can install Chocolatey packages that are stored in VSTS, but you have to supply the PAT, repository address and user name (although the latter can be a bogus value, it's not being used). Is there no way to have Chocolatey use the credential provider just like nuget is doing it?

**Update**:
After having added my Choco repository to the list of known repos, my chocolatey.config file looks like

```
  <sources>
    <source id="chocolatey" value="https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/" disabled="true" bypassProxy="false" selfService="false" priority="0" />    
    <source id="CompanyChoco" value="https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CompanyChoco/nuget/v2/" disabled="false" bypassProxy="false" selfService="false" priority="1" />
  </sources>
```

As suggested by @starain-MSFT, I've created a package.config file, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <packages>
    <package id="MyPackage" version="0.0.4"  source="https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CompanyChoco/nuget/v2/" />
  </packages>
```

I have also ensured that I have the latest version of CredentialProvider.VSS.exe installed in %appdata%\local\nuget\credentialproviders. 
When doing "choco install package.config", I still get prompted for username and password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it with these steps:

1. Define packages in [Packages.config](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/wiki/CommandsInstall#packagesconfig)
2. Call [choco source add command](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-sources) to add another source (using choco source list to check sources)
3. Call [choco install [packages.config] command](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-install) to install packages.

Comment: Following the link you mention in step 1, I see that packages.config is something used when you want to download a bunch of Choco packages, so I don't see how this will help. Steps 2-3 are exactly what I already did, but that is insufficient when the Choco packages are stored in VSTS. Please note that the question is about Choco packages stored in VSTS and not about Chocolatey repositories in general.

Comment: @SimonAx 1.The packages.config defines the packages that you want to install and you can specify the source for the package too. So can you provide the sample to explain your requirement? 2. Yes, the packages are stored in VSTS, the choco source add command is used to add your VSTS Feed, you can specify the priority (--priority, higher than others), then it will look for the packages from your VSTS feed first. BTW, the CredentialProvider.VSS.exe will help to authentication.

Comment: Problem solved: In step 2, make sure to add username and password. A hashed version of the PAT will be stored in the choco config file. The syntax is `choco sources add -n "NameOfRepo" -s "https://Company.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/CompanyChoco/nuget/v2/"`-u "DoesntMatter" -p "PAT" Connecting to the repo using v3 does not work though (also pointed out in link provided in original question).